# Improve excel RegExp user function by search and replace by list

Tags: regex, vba, excel, regexp-replace

I have simple vba user function in excel, that make replacement in text with RegEx:

```
Function RegExReplace (SearchPattern As String, TextToSearch As String, _
                          ReplacePattern As String, _
                          Optional GlobalReplace As Boolean = True, _
                          Optional IgnoreCase As Boolean = False, _
                          Optional MultiLine As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim RE As Object
    
    Set RE = CreateObject ( "vbscript.regexp")
    With RE
        .MultiLine = MultiLine
        .Global = GlobalReplace
        .IgnoreCase = IgnoreCase
        .Pattern = SearchPattern
    End With
    
    RegExReplace = RE.Replace (TextToSearch, ReplacePattern)
        
End Function
```

But it can search and replace only by one

- Search pattern (in cell C2) and one
 - Replace pattern (in cell D2)

So, what I want - when there is no matches to pattern from cell C2 - it take search and replace patterns from cells C3 and D3.

[image]

screen shot of more realistic example
[image]

Earlier I post a code that make replace by list of `RegEx` patterns, I think it may help:

```
Sub regexpreplace ()

    Set Myrange = ActiveSheet.Range ( "A2: A1000") 'range in which we make replace
    Set regrange = ActiveSheet.Range ( "B2: B6") 'range with RegExp pattern
    'In range C1: C6 we have pattern for replace
    
    For Each D In regrange        
        For Each C In Myrange
            Set rgx = CreateObject ( "VBScript.RegExp")
            rgx.IgnoreCase = True
            rgx.Pattern = D.Value
            rgx.Global = True
            C.Value = rgx.Replace (C.Value, D.Offset (0, 1) .Value)
        Next
    
    Next

End Sub
```

In this code:

A1: A1000 - range with input values

B1: B6 - list of RegExp patterns

C1: C6 - list of output patterns

So, how I can when there is no matches to pattern from cell C2 - it take search and replace patterns from cells C3 and D3?

Comment: Iterate through your pairs of Regex Patterns.  Use the `.Test` method to see if it matches and branch accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Surely there is a way to check whether regex matches, and check another regex if necessary, but why not use one which matches both case?

E.g. this one below selects second number in both scenarios:

- regex pattern: `.* \d+x(\d+)x?.*`
- replace to: `\1`

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/5hEUxY/1)

---

For your original question, to change regex, you can use something like this:

```
Sub regexpreplace()
    Dim Rgx As RegExp
    Dim MyRange As Range
    Dim RegRange As Range
    Dim C As Range
    Dim D As Range

    Set MyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A2: A1000")   'range in which we make replace
    Set RegRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2: B6")   'range with RegExp pattern
    'In range C1: C6 we have pattern for replace

    Set Rgx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Rgx.IgnoreCase = True
    Rgx.Global = True

    For Each C In MyRange
        rgxrow = 1
        Do
            Rgx.Pattern = RegRange.Cells(rgxrow, 1)
            If Rgx.Test(C) Then
                C.Value = Rgx.Replace(C.Value, RegRange(rgxrow, 2))
                rgxrow = D.Rows.Count + 1
            Else
                rgxrow = rgxrow + 1
            End If
        Loop Until rgxrow > D.Rows.Count
    Next C
End Sub
```

Comment: It work perfect, thank you! But I forget to say, that I have about 100 types of different data and I need some universal answer how to search by two and more patterns

Comment: Yes, Mate! It would be easier to combine all templates in a single column, but I share the extracted information on the various columns (about 20+), this I do not write, so I need exactly the formula in which you can specify a range of search patterns and replacement. I attach another image for a more clear example. By the way I cant run your macro it argue on second string